# Pandas groupby, sum and populate original dataframe

Tags: pandas, group-by

Here is my original df

```
import pandas as pd
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'color': ['blue', 'blue', 'yellow', 'yellow'], 'count': [1,3,4,5]})

color   count   
blue    1   
blue    3   
yellow  4   
yellow  5
```

I would like to group by color column and sum count column and then populate original dataframe with results. So final result should look like:

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'color': ['blue', 'blue', 'yellow', 'yellow'], 'count': [1,3,4,5], 
                     'total_per_color': [4,4,9,9]})


color   count   total_per_color
blue    1       4
blue    3       4
yellow  4       9
yellow  5       9
```

I can do it with groupby and sum and then merge using pandas, but I wonder if there is quicker way to do it? In SQL one can achieve it with `partition`, in R I can use `dplyr` and `mutate`. Is there something similar in pandas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `transform` with `groupby`

```
df_1['total_per_color']=df_1.groupby('color')['count'].transform('sum')
df_1
Out[886]: 
    color  count  total_per_color
0    blue      1                4
1    blue      3                4
2  yellow      4                9
3  yellow      5                9
```